# Mysql join & filter

Tags: mysql, sql, string, inner-join, aggregate-functions

How to Add another table as a condition in below query

i have below query

```
SELECT Group_concat(cl.name) AS category  FROM sco_category_product cp 
LEFT JOIN sco_category_lang cl ON (cp.id_category= cl.id_category) WHERE id_product = 3 AND cl.id_shop = 1
```

Gives me output

```
category
Juniors,Juniors size chart
```

I have a table `"sco_category`" that has `"id_category" & "active"` columns in it.

I want to make a query that merges with above query I've written & give me output of active `"id_category"` only.

For exg "`Juniors`" is name of "`id_category`" & if is not active i.e ("`active`" column has `0` value in it.) then its excluded from data.

Please share your thought on this.

Comment: Please provide CREATE TABLE for all 3 tables, some sample data as INSERT INTO, and desired output for this data. Also provide MySQL server version (not client program version! execute `SELECT VERSION();` and copy the output).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I follow you correctly, that's one more join:

```
select group_concat(cl.name) as category  
from sco_category_product cp 
inner join sco_category_lang cl on cp.id_category= cl.id_category 
inner join sco_category c on c.id_category = cl.id_category
where cp.id_product = 3 and cl.id_shop = 1 and c.active = 1
```